# Write multiple pages in single html

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, ionic-framework

I need to implement something like this jQuery structure in ionic framework

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <!--content -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <!--content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

I searched on google but not able to do that.

Currently I am having this in my html:

```
<body ng-app="todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<div id="page1">
    <header id="header" class="bar bar-header">

        <h3 class="title">header 1 is long</h3>
    </header>
    <content padding="true" id="">
    <div class="centered">
        <img alt="Flash Anatomy Muscles" src="images/thinkand.jpg"
            id="cover-img" />

    </div>
    </content>

    <div class="bar bar-footer">
        <div class="title">
            <button id="a" class="button button-light"
                ng-click="showAlert($event)">Origin</button>
            <button id="b" class="button button-light"
                ng-click="showAlert($event)">Insertion</button>
            <button id="c" class="button button-light"
                ng-click="showAlert($event)">Btn3</button>
            <button id="d" class="button button-light"
                ng-click="showAlert($event)">Btn4</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2">
    <header id="header" class="bar bar-header">

        <h3 class="title">header 2</h3>
    </header>

    <content padding="true" id="">
    <div class="centered">
        random text over here
    </div>
    </content>

    <div class="bar bar-footer">
        <div class="title">

            <button id="e" class="button button-light"
                ng-click="showAlert($event)">Btn5</button>
            <button id="f" class="button button-light"
                ng-click="showAlert($event)">Btnn6</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

It gives me this result:

[image]

Observe these:

1. Both pages' headers are overlapped.
2. Content of page 1 (image) is being displayed, and second page's text is being placed on image.
3. Footer of page 1 is being overlapped by footer of page 2. So only page 2's buttons are shown.

Can someone guide me what I need to do in ionic framework like `data-role` property of jquery?

P.S: I tried adding `data-role='page'` in the divs. That doesn't change the result at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ionic` doesn't use anything of `jQuery` at all, it uses `Angular JS` and I suggest that you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542).

About the single page structure, I'm afraid it isn't possible using `Ionic`, because `Ionic` implements [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), which creates routes for different templates (each template being a different html).

So, just get rid of `jQuery` and start thinking `Angular` as the posts suggests, you won't regret! ;)